# Adding custom layout to google's place picker(Android Studio )

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, google-places-api

I am using the place picker of google as a fragment in my app (it has no set content view method). When I change to place picker fragment the image I show on the top of fragment's in my activity is lost and all I see is the "view" that is provided by PlacePicker fragment. I have two problems.

1) I want to show the additional things in my layout.
2) I want to remove something (or at least change the texts in searchbar etc) from the view that is shown by place picker.

How can I accomplish this? I am providing the code I used for my activity's xml file and placepicker fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>


    <com.baoyachi.stepview.HorizontalStepView
        android:id="@+id/step_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_stepview">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class PlacePickerFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "PlacePickerSample";
    private static final int ACTION_PICK_PLACE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
            try {
                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(getActivity());
                // Start the Intent by requesting a result, identified by a request code.
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER);

            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil
                        .getErrorDialog(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), getActivity(), 0);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Google Play Services is not available.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

            // END_INCLUDE(intent)

    }

    /**
     * Extracts data from PlacePicker result.
     * This method is called when an Intent has been started by calling
     * {@link #startActivityForResult(Intent, int)}. The Intent for the
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker} is started with
     * {@link #REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER} request code. When a result with this request code is received
     * in this method, its data is extracted by converting the Intent data to a {@link Place}
     * through the
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker#getPlace(Intent,
     * android.content.Context)} call.
     *
     * @param requestCode
     * @param resultCode
     * @param data
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(activity_result)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER) {


            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, getActivity());
                final CharSequence name = place.getName();
                final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
                final CharSequence phone = place.getPhoneNumber();
                final String placeId = place.getId();
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: 0"+place.getLatLng().toString() );
                String attribution = PlacePicker.getAttributions(data);
                if(attribution == null){
                    attribution = "";
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Place selected: " + placeId + " (" + name.toString() + ")");

            } else {

            }

        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        // END_INCLUDE(activity_result)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you got the workaround